# Width of my ElevatedButton is not reducing

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

***The Width of the Elevated Button is not reducing, it is coming in taking all the width on the screen.The parent widget is ListView.I have even tried to reduce it through ButtomTheme but still it  is not working. I have added the code below. Everywhere I have seen the way to reduce the width is this way.But don't know why it is not reducing the width***

```
          ListView(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                RotatedBox(
                  quarterTurns: 3,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Sign Up',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 50,
                          fontFamily: 'Pacifico'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
                Text(
                  'BRUXTER',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 30,
                      fontFamily: 'RockSalt',
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            Form(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: 'Enter Your Name',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: 'Enter Your Email',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: 'Enter Your PassWord',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                  0.5, // Will take 50% of screen space
              child: ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Go to screen two'),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            )
            
          ],
```

[image]

Comment: This is because of ListView, is it necessary to use ListView here can't we use Column instead?

Comment: check [Understanding constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints) and follow 29 examples they provide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace your `ListView` with `Column`

```
Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              RotatedBox(
                quarterTurns: 3,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Sign Up',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 50,
                        fontFamily: 'Pacifico'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
              Text(
                'BRUXTER',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontFamily: 'RockSalt',
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
          ),
          Form(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: 'Enter Your Name',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),
                  ),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: 'Enter Your Email',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),
                  ),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: 'Enter Your PassWord',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                0.5, // Will take 50% of screen space
            child: ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Go to screen two'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
```

Comment: Thaank you so much Diwyansh, It is working now. But why wasn't it working under the ListView

Comment: In flutter constraints goes parent to child so parent has full control over the size of it's child.

Comment: But then the same thing goes for the Column as well.

Comment: Yes but Column has loose constraints so it's child are free as per their sizes.

Comment: ooh okaay. thank you Diwyansh for helping me understand this

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Column, I would actually recommend staying with ListView for performance reasons in most cases.
You could also fix this issue by wrapping the `Container` in a `Center` widget (or an `Align` if you want a different alignment than centered).
These widgets provide loose constraints to their children so they can be any size they want, but no larger than the parent, which is exactly what you want in this case.

It wasn't working in your case, because the `ListView` forces children to take up the entire width, so what size the direct children want to take up is ignored.

Comment: Oooh Okaay Thaank you so much, for explaining me so well.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below code

Replace width with margin in Container widget

```
Container(
//               Replace width with margin
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80.0,),
              
//               width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
//                   0.5, // Will take 50% of screen space
              child: ElevatedButton(
                
                child: Text('Go to screen two'),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            )
```

Complete code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          RotatedBox(
            quarterTurns: 3,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30.0),
              child: Text(
                'Sign Up',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 50, fontFamily: 'Pacifico'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Text(
            'BRUXTER',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
                fontFamily: 'RockSalt',
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          )
        ],
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 50,
      ),
      Form(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: 'Enter Your Name',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: 'Enter Your Email',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: 'Enter Your PassWord',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20,
      ),
      Container(
//               Replace width with margin
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 80.0,
        ),

//               width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
//                   0.5, // Will take 50% of screen space
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Go to screen two'),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thaank you so much It's working correctly..Can you pliss  help me understand 2 questions. Firstly, why wasn't it working before.Secondly, hardcoding the width like this..Will it look the same across bigger and smaller screen.

Comment: Sure, It was not working because you added width for the Container, and secondly for example I have hardcoded the value you can also use MediaQuery to set margin or padding for example like ***margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.20,
        ),***

Comment: oooh okaay, Thank you Tejaswini for helping me understand this